# PDFbox set visible when printing

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am working with PDFBOX and the documentation on it seems sparse so I've come here for some help. I am trying to print out a pdf form that I've created, with fields populated dynamically by eclipse. I can get it to import and print, but when I do print, the fields I've set don't show up (although they do when I save it to HDD). Can someone point me to the settings to set visible when printing? I saw itext had something similar, and I'm hoping that PDFBox does too.

Here is my current code.

```
PDDocument doc = null;

   try{
        doc = PDDocument.load("resources/orderForm.pdf");
        PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
        PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
        PDField field = acroForm.getField("Orderer");
        field.setValue("JohnTest");

} catch (IOException ie){
    System.out.println(ie);
}
//doc.addPage(new PDPage());
try{

    //doc.save("Empty PDF.pdf");
    doc.silentPrint();
    //doc.print();
    doc.close();
} catch (Exception io){
    System.out.println(io);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found my answer, can't use pdfbox to do it, although the alternative is just as simple. Use the desktop to print the file! example code as follows

```
    public void printOrder(){
    try {
        File myFile = new File(finished);
        //Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
        Desktop.getDesktop().print(myFile);
        doc.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // no application registered for PDFs
    }
}
```